# Не выводится аватар пользователя

Tags: python, discord.py

Не выводит аватар пользователя emb.set_image(url=member.avatar_url). Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать ?

```
async def userinfo(ctx,member:nextcord.Member = None, guild: nextcord.Guild = None):
        #if member is None:
        member = ctx.author
        emb = nextcord.Embed(title="Информация о пользователе", color=member.color)
        emb.add_field(name="Имя:", value=member.display_name,inline=False)
        emb.set_image(url=member.avatar_url)
        emb.add_field(name="Айди пользователя:", value=member.id,inline=False)
        emb.add_field(name="Роль на сервере:", value=f"{member.top_role.mention}",inline=False)
        emb.add_field(name="Уровень на сервере:", value=f"{cursor.execute('SELECT lvl FROM  users'.format()).fetchone()[0]}", inline=False)
        emb.add_field(name="Предупреждение на сервере:",value=f"{cursor.execute('SELECT warn FROM  users'.format()).fetchone()[0]}", inline=False)
        emb.add_field(name="Акаунт был создан:", value=member.created_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"),inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed = emb)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В [`nextcord`](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#nextcord.Member.avatar) нет `avatar_url`

```
async def userinfo(ctx,member:nextcord.Member = None, guild: nextcord.Guild = None):
        member = ctx.author if not member else member
        member_avatar = member.avatar if member.avatar else member.display_avatar
        emb = nextcord.Embed(title="Информация о пользователе", color=member.color)
        emb.add_field(name="Имя:", value=member.display_name,inline=False)
        emb.set_image(url=member_avatar)
        emb.add_field(name="Айди пользователя:", value=member.id,inline=False)
        emb.add_field(name="Роль на сервере:", value=f"{member.top_role.mention}",inline=False)
        emb.add_field(name="Уровень на сервере:", value=f"{cursor.execute('SELECT lvl FROM  users'.format()).fetchone()[0]}", inline=False)
        emb.add_field(name="Предупреждение на сервере:",value=f"{cursor.execute('SELECT warn FROM  users'.format()).fetchone()[0]}", inline=False)
        emb.add_field(name="Акаунт был создан:", value=member.created_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"),inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed = emb)
```